# C# Identity modify custom properties

Tags: c#, properties, identity

Hello I Have created custom ApiUser class which inherits from IdentityUser.

```
 public class ApiUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The question it is set on Creating new user, but how do I change it/update it later?

```
 UserManager<ApiUser> userManager
```

_userManager does not seem to have any methotds to do so.

Comment: Do you want those informations to be added to the claims? Also, please specify what framework you are using - oid is a very broad topic, and identity the wrong tag for it.

Comment: No i dont need this information added to the claims, I am using .net 6  web api. I just want to update it in database

Comment: there's a lot missing to help you - what user store are you using -> "database" is not sufficient, as UserManager can have a variety of stores. Your easiest bet is to simply query the database directly through EF instead of trying to redirect it through the asp net identity API on update

Comment: Thanks just figure it out.  Used _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

Comment: seems like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateUserDetails")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateUser(ApiUserUpdate apiUserUpdate)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(apiUserUpdate.Email);
        if(user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("No user found with given email");
        }

        user.FirstName = apiUserUpdate.FirstName;
        user.LastName = apiUserUpdate.LastName;
        await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

        return Ok("user updated");
    }
```